# I just had an email from wordpress. what does it mean?

Tags: email

I just had this email from WordPress:

```
A new pingback on the post "Contact Us" is waiting for your approval
http://clickcomputers.org.uk/contact-us/

Website : Click Computers &raquo; Post Topic &raquo; Be Creative. (IP: 217.160.66.224 , kundenserver.de)
URL : http://clickcomputers.org.uk/be-creative/
Pingback excerpt: 
[...] Contact Us [...]
```

What does this mean?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That means you have been linked from that page (See Codex for [PingBack](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pingbacks))

> **A Quote from Codex -**
>   Pingbacks were designed to solve some of the problems that people saw with trackbacks. The official pingback documentation makes pingbacks sound an awful lot like trackbacks: